# Complex stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

[PEOPLE]

```
PEOPLE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME
```

[ADDRESS]

```
ADDRESS_ID, PEOPLE_ID, ADDRESS, EMAIL 
(3, 1, 120 Woodland Road, <mailto:lyndon@foo.com> Lyndon@foo.com  )
```

Each person may have zero or more addresses.

I tried to write a stored procedure which will return each person’s full name as a single field and his/her email address in the resultset. If the email address does not exist, return the string ‘No Email’.

I tried:

```
Select 
    ppl.Last_Name, 
    (select 
        CASE 
            WHEN Addr.Email is null THEN 'No Email' 
            ELSE Addr.Email 
        END AS Email 
        FROM [Address] AS Addr 
        where ppl.ID = Addr.PEOPLE_ID
    )
FROM [PEOPLE] AS ppl
```

When I exec that query I got error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression

Can anyone help me to fix the query? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, what do you want the query to return when there is more than one email?

Comment: You should avoid describing problems like this as "complex". Since you don't, currently, know how to solve the problem, then by definition you're not in a position to judge its complexity. For anyone who does know solution(s) to the problem, they may not describe it as complex

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to be like below using `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` function

```
SELECT ppl.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + ppl.Last_Name as Name,
ISNULL(Addr.Email, 'No Email') as Email
FROM [Address] AS Addr 
JOIN [PEOPLE] AS ppl ON ppl.ID = Addr.PEOPLE_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine, if you limit the results to at most one email per person.  Lacking information on what you want to do in this case, the following query takes the approach of choosing an arbitrary email:

```
SELECT ppl.Last_Name, 
       ISNULL( (SELECT TOP 1 Addr.Email 
                FROM [Address] AS Addr 
                WHERE ppl.ID = Addr.PEOPLE_ID
               ), 'No Email') as Email
FROM PEOPLE AS ppl;
```

If you want a separate row for each email, you can use `LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT p.last_name, COALESCE(a.Email, 'No Email') as email
FROM people p LEFT JOIN
     address a
     on a.people_id = p.id;
```